# transition effect not working when closing a modal

Tags: css, angularjs

I use the following style to enable transition effects:

```
.ng-hide .bar {
  height: 0px;
}


.bar {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

The issue is, when closing the box, the transition effects do not work.
Any clue how to fix this ?

Link to plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/B5LBwKSmL13BOoGuBhSx

Comment: Insufficient data provided, even Sherlock Holmes would have no clue. What property changes on modal show/hide? Do you have live url?

Comment: Jeez, you are skimpy on words, too :D

Answer (score 0):

The style that stops the animation is:

```
.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate) {display: none !important;}
```

If you remove it, than you will get other problems. Looking at css class name and what happens in here, I have a clue that you did this all wrong.